# WooCommerce - Adding open and close div tags in content-single-product.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

> I want to add on [**templates/content-single-product.php**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php#L39):
>   **•** An opening **`<div>`** before line 39 
>   **•** A close **`</div>`** after line 81.

Copying this template to my active theme and make the customization just works fine.

**However is there a better way to do this without copying the template?**

I thought I had seen some way to apply a filter to `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );` and `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );` to do something similar.

I just wanted to check the way I am doing, **is the correct way**.

**Is the way I have chose, the right way?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In template [**`content-single-product.php`**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php#L39), The only way to have your open **`<div>`**, is the template herself, as you want it before (line 39):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Because if you use **`woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`** your open **`<div>`** is going to be **after** that existing **`<div itemscope itemtype="…">`** and not **before**.

For the closing , as you are editing your template, the best way is to add it in your template (just as you made it.

But it should work too in **`woocommerce_after_single_product`** hook with any kind of priority (as nothing is already hooked in); this way for example:

```
function single_product_closing_div(){
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'single_product_closing_div', 10, 0 );
```

> **Conclusion:** You have done it the right way, in the template directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do that by adding two hooks for `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` and `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` so they will look like this

> add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','your_function_name',1);
>   add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','another_function_name',99);
>   function your_function_name(){echo ""; }
>   function another_function_name(){echo ""; }

Comment: But the add_action would be place in the copied template too right? In that case (and as this is not to be included elsewhere) wouldn't that be overkill? I may already have the right answer I just want to know it is the most efficient way of doing it.